# Linear algebra: Find BA given Col(A) is in Null(B)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Found an exercise and not really sure how to go about it, any helped greatly appreciated!

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are matrices such that $\operatorname{Col}(A) \subset \operatorname{Null}(B)$. Find $BA$.

Again thanks in advance for any advice!
James

Comment: Think of $A$ as a collection of column vectors.  What does $B$ do to each of them?

Answer (score 4):

The statement 
$$
\operatorname{Col}(A) \subset \operatorname{Null}(B)
$$
means that for every $v\in \operatorname{Col}(A)$ we have $B v=0$. But every element $v\in \operatorname{Col}(A)$ is of the form $v=Ax$. Hence $BAx=0$ for all $x$. What does this say about $BA$?

Comment: Thanks very much, brain obviously fried after a long day!